# .NET WebMethod with xhrHttpRequest File Upload

Tags: ajax, vb.net, webmethod, form-data

I am trying to do an asynchronous file upload using JavaScript in combination with a WebMethod in VB.NET

JavaScript:

```
xhr.open('POST', "upload.aspx/upload", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var formData = new FormData();

// append the files
for (var i in files) {
   formData.append(base.el.name, files[i]);
}

xhr.send(formData);
```

VB.NET:

```
<Web.Services.WebMethod(enableSession:=True)> _
Public Shared Function upload() As String
    Return "Hello World!"
End Function
```

If I use **content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, or **multipart/form-data** the WebMethod does not get hit, if I use **content-type=application/json**, the WebMethod is hit, but the response is a 500 with message: *Invalid JSON primitive: ------WebKitFormBoundary ...*

Is there a way to make the AJAX WebMethod work with multipart form data?

Answer (score 2):

Seems .NET will not allow the **multipart/form-data** for the content-type:

[JSON Hijacking and How ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 Avoids these Attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks)[1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks)

> There is a built-in validation layer of protection that ASP.NET
>   enforces for both GET and POST based ASP.NET AJAX web methods, which
>   is that regardless of the HTTP verb being used, **ASP.NET always
>   requires that the HTTP Content-Type header is set to the value
>   application/json**. It this content type header is not sent, ASP.NET
>   AJAX will reject the request on the server.

Seems the best way is to handle this using a generic .ashx file instead