# How to receive a file from c # via ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to send a file through ajax and it is not possible to save it, someone to help me, I have already tried several serialized but not one that works. acontinuauacion I show you the client side code and the server side, it would be useful if you help me if I'm doing it right or there is another way with [webmethod] to do it

```js
$("#btnCargar").on("click", function() {
  var filese = $("#fileComparendo")[0].files[0];
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("archivo", filese);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%=ResolveUrl("addcomp.aspx/prueba")%>",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      console.log("CallWM" + data.d);
      alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
      alert(err.Message)
      console.log("Ajax Error!");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="text" id="txtPrueba" class="form-contrav" />
    <input type="file" class="file-name" id="fileComparendo" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cargar" id="btnCargar" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
[WebMethod]
public static  string prueba(HttpContext archivo)
{
   // var recipient = Request["Recipient"];
    var re =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["archivo"];
    archivo.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/");
    string[] files;
    int numFiles;
    files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
    numFiles = files.Length;
    numFiles = numFiles + 1;
    string str_image = "";
    foreach (string s in archivo.Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = archivo.Request.Files[s];
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
            string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/") + str_image;
            file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
        }
    }
    archivo.Response.Write(str_image);
    return "hola";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[WebMethod]` can only accept a content type of application/json, but you can use an .ashx: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26273565/1429439

Add a new Generic Handler called `Upload.ashx`, then replace `ProcessRequest()` with:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext archivo)
        {
            var re = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["archivo"];
            archivo.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

            string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/");
            string[] files;
            int numFiles;
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
            numFiles = files.Length;
            numFiles = numFiles + 1;
            string str_image = "";
            foreach (string s in archivo.Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = archivo.Request.Files[s];
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                {
                    fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
                    string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/") + str_image;
                    file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
                }
            }
            archivo.Response.Write(str_image);
        }
```

Update the url in `$.ajax()` to point to `Upload.ashx` with:

```
url: "<%=ResolveUrl("Upload.ashx")%>",
```

Comment: You can help me with an example, is that I am new in software development

Comment: Hello friend, you are trying with the generic driver, but it has not been configured as the administrator in webconfig